# HTTP connections work, SSH does not GitLab

Tags: ruby, git, ssh, gitlab

I'm using Bitnami's GitLab Community Edition 8.4.2 acquired from the AWS marketplace. I am unable to use SSH to push, pull, or do anything with Git.  HTTP works fine.

Via the gitlab interface, the git user can have public keys added and removed for the various registered users. In watching the authorized_keys at /home/git/.ssh, I can see that it is in fact getting updated as users are modified.

I got to thinking that I may have somehow gotten my authorized_keys file out of sync, therefore, supposedly running

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:shell:setup RAILS_ENV=production
```

should fix it right up, but when I do run that I get the error

```
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

is /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/.bundle the said bundle directory? If I cd there and run the same command I get

```
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:292:in `block in replace_gem': rake is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
from /opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
```

and this is where I am at a loss. I wish I would have read that Ruby book.

Comment: What happens when you ssh? Do you get an error? Try `ssh -v git@yourhost.com` and see if it even authenticates. If it can't authenticate, nothing related to git will happen either.

Comment: Putty returns "Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)" Hoever, every entry in the authorized_keys file for the git user has something similar to 'command="/opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell key-4"' so it looks to me like the git user does not get shell access.

Comment: Well, I may have been wrong about git not getting shell access. The file gitlab-shell checks the argument/parameter (key) being passed, in the case above that would be key-4. I'm looking at this script trying to decipher it, but if you have some insight, I'm all ears.